# Bootstrap 4. Почему размер navbar настолько мал?

Tags: css, bootstrap

Адаптирую сайт под мобильные телефоны, столкнулся с такой проблемой что navbar который идет в примерах bootstrap невероятно мал. Приходиться на телефоне приближать экран, что за бред вообще?

Такое чувство что экран остается компьютерный на мобильной версии.

Мой код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="img/favicon.ico" rel="icon">
    <title>Главная страница</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="d-flex h-100 p-3 mx-auto flex-column">
        <header class="mb-auto">
                <div class="container">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="font-size: 16px;">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img alt="" height="125" src="images/logo.png" width="240"></a> <button aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" class="navbar-toggler" data-target="#navbarNav" data-toggle="collapse" type="button"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
                        <div class="collapse text-center navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto text-uppercase">
                                <li class="nav-item active">
                                    <a class="nav-link text-info" href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-messenger"></i> Форум <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link text-info" href="#"><i class="far fa-user-circle"></i> Личный кабинет</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link text-info" href="/news.html"><i class="fab fa-neos"></i> Новости</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link text-info" href="#"><i class="fas fa-piggy-bank"></i> Донат</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link text-info" href="#"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i> FAQ</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
        </header>
        <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/holder.min.js"></script> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Должен быть таким, удобным размером с палец: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А у меня такой - маленький и нужно экран увеличивать...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте в `head` после `<meta charset="utf-8">` следующее:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

Это указано в [офф документации](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/) по bootstrap4

Comment: спасибо, думал это лишний код.